# Maven projects disappeared from project explorer in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

So I Just created a Maven Project , It was created successfully without any error but maven package are missing from project explorer in eclipse. Although projects are present in workspace folder. The name of artifact is(or Project name) was junit But it is Missing from project explorer. I have attached an screenshot pls have a look into that. The projects created with names junit and junit2 are missing , do not get confuse with JunitTesting which is there in screenshot, it is different one than maven projects .
Help please..
[image: Package Explorer in Ecilipse]

Answer (score 0):

Removing the filters worked for me , Select Dropdown in package explorer then Select > Customize View > Filter > and unselect all of them